# I used to "eth0", why now we have "enp3s0" and "ens3"?

Tags: networking, server, static-ip, ifconfig, virtualbox-networking

So ... I remember vaguely how to setup network with static IP. 
I got dedicated server from [ikoula](http://ikoula.com/) and for some stupid reason, it doesn't have DHCP.

Before, I would just add the static IP to `/etc/network/interfaces`. Now everything seems not working.

I do have some other questions though. This same partition is booted from VirtualBox/QEMU and have `ens3` as network interfaces, and booted directly (reboot), it has `enp2s0` as interfaces! Why?

**and where is eth0?**

To add more informations, this is Lubuntu on server environment. Yes it is stupid, but I don't want to talk about that.

Comment: Because Predictable Network Interface Names are predictable.  Welcome to the world that is systemd :+

Comment: @Rinzwind let God forgive whoever made systemd, because I can't.

Comment: Your network settings, if you are running lubuntu; i.e. LXDE, belong in Network Manager.